# Getting InputStream errors when including a call to ElementData within an Import definition

Tags: import, streams

So I am writing an `ImportExport` converter for a common chemistry file format, and I've run up against a problem that seems to be about shared streams and whatnot.  I followed the directions on [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DevelopingAnImportConverter.html).

To work the example, create a random text file whose contents do not matter.

```
Export["testfile.txt", "hello"];
```

The definition for the `Import` converter is as follows

```
ImportExport`RegisterImport["TestFormat", TestFormat`TestFormatImport];
TestFormat`TestFormatImport[filename_String, options___] := 
 Module[{temp},
  (*Do some stuff, all works just fine*)
  temp = ElementData["C", "AtomicNumber"];
  {"Test" -> temp}];
```

All this does is call for the atomic number associated with the symbol C.  If you test it out it seems to work just fine:

```
In[3]:= Import["testfile.txt",{"TestFormat","Test"}]
Out[3]= 6
```

But any subsequent call to `ElementData` gives a stream error:

```
In[4]:= ElementData["F","AtomicNumber"]
During evaluation of In[4]:= General::openx: InputStream[C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\ElementData-7.0.28\Data\ElementData.wdx,122] is not open. >>
During evaluation of In[4]:= BinaryRead::openx: InputStream[C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Paclets\Repository\ElementData-7.0.28\Data\ElementData.wdx,122] is not open. >>
Out[4]= $Failed
```

But, if I make a call to `ElementData` *before* I make the `Import` command, then the errors go away.

```
In[1]:= ImportExport`RegisterImport["TestFormat", 
            TestFormat`TestFormatImport];
        TestFormat`TestFormatImport[filename_String, options___] := 
            Module[{temp},
           (*Do some stuff, all works just fine*)
           temp = ElementData["C", "AtomicNumber"];
           {"Test" -> temp}];
        ElementData["H", "AtomicNumber"]
        Import["testfile.txt", {"TestFormat", "Test"}]
        ElementData["F", "AtomicNumber"]

Out[3]= 1

Out[4]= 6

Out[5]= 9
```

This is all well and good, but I don't want to have to randomly make a call to `ElementData` before I do an `Import` command every time.

What is going on here and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: I am curious, did you make any progress? I am just facing a very similar problem, with `CountryData` and webMathematica...

Comment: I just asked a "similar" question, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33783/countrydata-et-al-and-associated-inputstream. Probably close to dupe, but hopefully this will bring us closer to the solution

Comment: No progress on this yet.  I heard from someone else that wasn't able to reproduce my error.  So I need to try it on my home PC to see if it is just a problem with my local installation or if it's more general.